# Как сделать "трехуровневый" форк?

Tags: сервер, perl, multiprocessing

В общем, есть такой скрипт, который запускает сервер:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use CGI;
use DBI;
use FCGI::ProcManager qw(pm_manage pm_pre_dispatch pm_post_dispatch
pm_change_process_name);
use FCGI;
use POSIX qw(setuid setsid);
use Encode qw(decode encode _utf8_on);
use Cache::Memcached;
use Cache::Memcached::Fast;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);


# my $dbh=DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test_db1;host=localhost","root","toor",{AutoCommit=>1})
#     or print "mysql connect fail\n";
# $dbh->{mysql_auto_reconnect} = 1;
my $cache = new Cache::Memcached::Fast({
    servers => [{address => 'localhost:11211', weight => 2.5 }],
    namespace => 'exp:',
    connect_timeout => 0.2,
    io_timeout => 1.0,close_on_error => 1,
    compress_threshold => 100_000,
    compress_ratio => 0.9,
    compress_methods => [
    \&IO::Compress::Gzip::gzip,
    \&IO::Uncompress::Gunzip::gun,
    zip ],
    max_failures => 3,
    failure_timeout => 2,
    ketama_points => 100,
    nowait => 0,
    serialize_methods => [
        \&Storable::freeze,
        \&Storable::thaw
    ],
    utf8 => ($^V >= 5.008001 ? 1 : 0),
});

system("killall perl-fcgi-pm");
sleep(1);
fork_proc() && exit 0;
print 1;
setsid() or die "Can't set sid: $!";
#33 - uid www-data
setuid(33) or die "Can't set uid: $!";# Запущенный скрипт будет слушать 8090 порт



my $socket = FCGI::OpenSocket("127.0.0.1:8090", 1000);
my $request = FCGI::Request(\*STDIN, \*STDOUT, \*STDERR, \%ENV, $socket);
# будет 3 дочерних процессов
pm_manage(n_processes => 3);
pm_change_process_name("perl-fcgi-lab3");
# бесконечный цикл, который будет обрабатывать запросы
while($request->Accept() >= 0) {
    pm_pre_dispatch();

    my @items = @{$cache->get('items')};
    my $query = CGI->new();
    my $t = $query->param("t");
    print "Content-Type: text/html\n";
    print "\n";
    if ($t eq "save") {
        my $fio = $query->param("fio");
        my %item = ( fio => $fio);

        push(@items, \%item);
    }
    print "<html><head></head><body>";
    print "$_->{fio} <br>" for @items;
    print"--<form action='/index.pl'>".
    "<input type='hidden' name='t' value='save'>".
    "<input type='text' name='fio'>".
    "<input type='submit'>".
    "</form>".
    "</body></html>";
    $cache->set('items', \@items);
    undef @CGI::QUERY_PARAM;
    pm_post_dispatch();
};
$dbh->disconnect();

sub fork_proc {
    my $pid;
    FORK: {
        if (defined($pid = fork)) {
            return $pid;
        }
        elsif ($! =~ /No more process/) {
            sleep 5;
            redo FORK;
        }
        else {
            die "Can't fork: $!";
        };
    };
};
sub reopen_std {
    open(STDIN, "+>/dev/null") or die "Can't open STDIN: $!";
    open(STDOUT, "+>&STDIN") or die "Can't open STDOUT: $!";
    open(STDERR, "+>&STDIN") or die "Can't open STDERR: $!";
};
```

Задача - переделать данный скрипт так, чтобы он запускал 3 процесса, в которых 3 подпроцесса. Тоесть, сделать трехуровневый такой себе стак процессов. (зачем - не знаю, задание у меня такое)

Comment: А что именно у вас не выходит ? можете спокойно вызывать ваш fork_proc в процессах потомках

Comment: Не выходит понять, с чего бы начать и куда код тулить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось прозаично. Нужно

```
# будет 3 дочерних процессов
pm_manage(n_processes => 3);
pm_change_process_name("perl-fcgi-lab3");
```

поменять на

```
# будет 3 дочерних процессов
pm_manage(n_processes => 3);
pm_manage(n_processes => 3);
pm_change_process_name("perl-fcgi-lab3");
```